# Why there is .desktop file in new Unity based ubuntu OS?

Tags: .desktop

I could find .desktop files in unity based Ubuntu. Can anyone explain it simply?

Answer (score 0):

`*.desktop` files are shortcuts. Your question is way too general, so this is as much as I'm able to answer :)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. Kindly read question and re-consider your possible duplicate suggestion.( Answer of Tatt's question : `sudo find /path_to_folder/ -iname *.desktop`)